# CSS for elements ONLY under a specific id

Tags: css

I have a div element that has an id and this div contains a set of inputs and labels.  I ONLY want to style the inputs inside this specific div but .. the following styles everything (global) instead of keeping the scope inside #ParentDiv

```
#ParentDiv label,input { display: inline; }
```

Also, is it possible to do this type of thing with valid css in IE6/7?

Comment: this link can be useful https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: I am having this issue and the problem seems to be with the `display` attribute. All others like border-radius or background-color only affect the expected child elements

Answer (score 99, accepted):

you need this:

```
#ParentDiv label, #ParentDiv input { display: inline; }
```

A comma indicates a new selector statement.

Often, so that I remember what each of the selectors is, and to make it easier to see what elements are being selected at a glance, I will alphabetize and break the selectors on two separate lines like so:

```
#ParentDiv input,
#ParentDiv label {
    display: inline;
}
```

Also, this should work just fine in IE 6/7/8, and is valid according to w3c.

Comment: For people looking to style a class instead of a tag name, use `#ParentDiv.myClass`.

Comment: @Noumenon Don't we need a space before `.myClass`?

Comment: Might seem weird but I've tested other elements than `display` and, unlike `display` itself, they work as expected, affecting only the children of a certain id or class. Any clue on why `display` works differently?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the above answer did not help me.
I wanted to style a table header so I had to append the `table` tag before the id like this:

```css
table#table_id th {
  width: 20%;
}
```

I hope this will help someone down the line.